# How to optimize a large number of if-else if-else expressions

Tags: javascript, if-statement, listjs

here is the some sample line of codes..

```
if(loc > 0 || cat > 0 || price > 0 || jsBed <= bedroom || jsBuilt >= built) {    
 /// Condition to checn all true
    return true;
} else if(loc < 0 || cat > 0 || price > 0 || jsBed <= bedroom || jsBuilt >= built) { 
   /////// 1 false other are true 

} else if(loc > 0 || cat < 0 || price > 0 || jsBed <= bedroom || jsBuilt >= built) { 

}
```

How to handle these condition.
if i have 5 statement. Then it must be almost 12+ condition one by one.. if i am checking all the 5 combinations its going to more lines of code do we have any better option to check all the conditions.

Comment: From the 3 above you're repeating the last 3 checks, you could check them once and nest an if statement if for the remainder.

Comment: So you want to have an if-elseif-else branch with all possibilities of those variables?  `price > 0 || jsBed <= bedroom || jsBuilt >= built` appears duplicate. Not sure if you want to check eg `jsBed > bedroom` ?

Comment: Are you trying to find the total number of conditions met? (2nd and 3rd condition should be treated the same)? Or do you have different implementations depending on which condition is met?

Comment: Based on the comments, you want to use AND `&&` instead or OR `||`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you treat a boolean expression as an integer in javascript, it will evaluate to `0` (for `false`) or `1` (for `true`). So you could sum the conditions and then use a switch-case construct to check how many were true:

```
var numTrue = 
   (loc > 0) + (cat > 0) + (price > 0) + (jsBed <= bedroom) + (jsBuilt >= built);

switch(numTrue) {
    case 0:
        // do something if no condition is met
        break;
    case 1:
        // do something else if one condition is met
        break;
    // etc...
}
```

Comment: It's looks reasonable.. I am thinking about it.. Thanks @Mureinik

Comment: @MArfan As per given information, this is one of the best solution, but if there are any other combinations, please add them to question. There can be other approaches that can help.

Comment: So loc=0,cat=1 is treated as loc=1,cat=0. This does not solve OP's example. It only checks the total number of met condition.

Comment: Actually, I might be wrong, this might be what OP was looking for although its not clearly stated.

Comment: If you want to be able to check a specific condition, just shift the tests by an increasing value, for example : `var numTrue = 
   (loc > 0) + ( (cat > 0) << 1) + ( (price > 0) << 2) + ( (jsBed <= bedroom) << 3) + ( (jsBuilt >= built) << 4);`

Answer (score 4):

You have condition that will never be met :

```
if(loc > 0 || cat > 0 || price > 0 || jsBed <= bedroom || jsBuilt >= built){    
    /// Condition to checn all true
    return true;
} else if(loc < 0 || cat > 0 || price > 0 || jsBed <= bedroom || jsBuilt >= built) { 
/////// 1 false other are true 

} else if(loc > 0 || cat < 0 || price > 0 || jsBed <= bedroom || jsBuilt >= built) { 

}
```

Basically :

- On the second else if, the condition  `cat > 0 || price > 0 || jsBed <= bedroom || jsBuilt >= built` is useless ebcause already met in the first one. Since you use an `else if` they will have already enter in the first if. So the only one that matter is `loc < 0`.
- Same for last `elseif` only `cat < 0` is relevant.

So it can be rewritten to

```
if(loc > 0 || cat > 0 || price > 0 || jsBed <= bedroom || jsBuilt >= built){    
    /// Condition to checn all true
    return true;
} else if(loc < 0) { 
/////// 1 false other are true 

} else if(cat < 0) { 

}
```

This answer assume that the code provided is the one that you're trying to simplify and not a generic sample.

Note : I think you may have not written what you wanted to do, forgetting some AND instead of OR.

Comment: That's what I was thinking after I read the question, "That's a lot of useless  checks."

Comment: @Walfrat. I appreciate your effort. I want to return true only if my condition match. Once match it will not move forward.. Because we know in JavaScript once return true or false. thanks

Comment: i think it will reduce the checks. and condition remain as it is.

Answer (score 3):

5 conditions is 2**5, i.e. 32 combinations.

If you want to check for various combination, without repeating the tests, you can bit-shift the individual results and combine them for a switch statement.
working with the numbers directly is succinct but not very readable

```js
var loc=1,cat=0,price=0,jsBed=1,bedroom=0,jsbuilt=0,built=1;

let results=[loc > 0,cat > 0,price > 0,jsBed <= bedroom,jsbuilt >= built];
let bits=results.reduce( (accum,current,index)=>accum+(current<<index), 0);
switch(bits){
case 0: // none
 break;
case 3: // first two
 break;
case 4: // third one
 break;
}
```

modifying this to use constants would make the switch statement more readable

```js
var loc=0,cat=1,price=0,jsBed=1,bedroom=0,jsbuilt=0,built=1;

const locBit=1<<0;
const catBit=1<<1;
const priceBit=1<<2;
const bedBit=1<<3;
const builtBit=1<<4;
let bits=( loc > 0 )*locBit |
         ( cat > 0 )*catBit |
         ( price > 0 )*priceBit |
         ( jsBed <= bedroom )*bedBit |
         ( jsbuilt >= built )*builtBit;
switch(bits){
  case 0:
      console.log("!loc,!cat,!price,!bed,!built");
      break;
  case catBit|locBit:
      console.log("loc,cat,!price,!bed>!built");
      break;
  default:
      console.log(bits);
}
```

you could use constants to help

Answer (score 1):

*edit1: modified for javascript, not java. Oops...*

I'm not sure if you want to see all combinations, but you can group them by introducing an numeric value for each possible output.

Concretely there are 5 variables and 2 options each variable? I've setup a table with numbers in binary representation. If there are > 2 options each(or at some) variable you have to use numbers (base 10). You can use binary values like

```
const locVal  = (loc > 0 ? 0x1 : 0x0) << 0;
const catVal  = (cat < 0 ? 0x1 : 0x0) << 1;
const priceVal= (price < 0 ? 0x1 : 0x0) << 2;
ect
```

So you can group them in a method:

```
function foo(trueCond, level) {
    return (trueCond ? 0b1 : 0b0) << level;
}
```

which makes

```
const locVal  = foo(loc > 0, 0);
const catVal  = foo(cat > 0, 1);
const priceVal= foo(price > 0, 2)
```

(I have omitted the other vars...) Then add up the binary values

```
const total = locVal + catVal + priceVal
```

Then you now have to use a switch case statement like

```
switch (total) {
    case 0: // all options negative
    case 1: // only loc is positive
    case 2: // only cat is positive
    case 3: // both loc and cat is positive
    ect
}
```

The values in the `case` represents the integer value of the binary sequence present in `total`. It has to be noted that it is extremely important to **document** the code very well, especially the case blocks, so that other readers can figure out directly which value stands for what (like i did).

If there are more than two options per variable, you can work in factors of 10 (like in method foo, use `(trueCond ? 1 : 0) * Math.pow(10, level)`)

Comment: This is not a Java question.

Answer (score 0):

Since your 3 conditions are fixed, you can have them first, followed by others, which can be converted to switch-case.

```
if(price > 0 || jsBed <= bedroom || jsBuilt >= built) {
    var locCheck = (loc > 0) ? 1 : 0;
    var catCheck = (cat > 0) ? 1 : 0;
    switch(locCheck + catCheck){
        case 0:
            break;
        case 1:
            break;
        case 2:
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: `(loc > 0) ? 1 : 0` can be replaced as `+(loc > 0)`. Also as OP has multiple OR condition, even if last 3 conditions are false, code has to be executed. Your code will not work

Comment: This is not equivalent to OP's code. If `price > 0 || jsBed <= bedroom || jsBuilt >= built` is `false` when `loc` & `cat` are positive numbers, the code will not execute at all. While in OP's code first `if` statement body will execute.

Comment: Hmm, you are right @Tushar. And tweaking it would result to similar as Mureinik

Comment: `case 1` would require an additional conditional with in it to determine whether `loc` or `cat` was `>0`. Alternatively, you could use different values for `locCheck` and `catCheck`. eg, 1 & 2 would give you 0, 1, 2 & 3 as the cases.